Recreating a custom bplist-derivative data type
I am trying to recreate a custom file type used by an iOS app. I analyzed its binary (image below)

and it seems to be a bplist00, however I can't inspect it with any tools like plutil. Plutil returns with an error:

non-NSData data argument passed to method

How could I better understand the structure of this file and how it differs from a regular plist?
I would be grateful for any suggestions on how to proceed and learning-resource recommendations.

I would use an open source plist library or tool in a programming language you are familiar with and then load the file while debugging the tool. This allows you to see the internal states and the file-offset when things go wrong.
